# How to merge CSS files in via config file magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, configuration

How I can merge CSS files using the `app/etc/config.php` file in magento 2? I want to enable this so I can improve the loading times of my website.

What's the right code to achieve this?

Comment: using config.php means ???

Comment: Somewhere I read that , for merging CSV you need to update config file. Is not true , please let me know how to merge it ? I am new to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

To add it in to your **config.php** file is a bit more convoluted than via the database. The database key is `dev/css/merge_css_files` under `core_config_data`. You probably have a value for it if you run:

```sql
MySQL [db]> select * from core_config_data where path like 'dev/%';
```

which will display all of your dev config settings.

The **easy** way to see exactly what needs to get added is to run `bin/magento app:config:dump`, which will toss all of your system configuration in to your `app/etc/config.php` file. However, below is an explanation of how the configuration under your config.php file is stored:

To add it in to your config file, you need to understand that each slash in the path adds a new key to the array, so `dev/css/merge_css_files` would expand to:

```php
'dev' => [
    'css' => [
        'merge_css_files' => value,
        // other "dev/css/%" settings
    ],
    // other "dev/%" settings
]
```

There's then which **scope** it's under (global, website, or store) which is the previous key in the array. In this case, it'll be **default** which is synonymous for global. The expanded array then looks like:

```php
'default' => [
    'dev' => [
        'css' => [
            'merge_css_files' => value,
            // other "dev/css/%" settings
        ],
        // other "dev/%" settings
    ],
    // other config values stored in the default scope
],
```

That array needs to go under the `system` key inside your `app/etc/config.php` file:

```php
return [
    'modules' => [
        // ... your module definitions
    ],
    'scopes' => [
        // ... your scope definitions
    ],
    'themes' => [
        // ... your theme definitions
    ],
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'dev' => [
                'css' => [
                    'merge_css_files' => 1, //1 = true, 0 = false
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Since the config is a boolean value in this case, the desired value is **1** which evaluates to **true**.

You then need to run `bin/magento app:config:import` to add the config back in to the system. You may then need to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to create the new assets.